# double quotes should be single quote error in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How to resolve prod build error?

> ERROR: /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/app/app.component.spec.ts[1, 32]: "
>   should be ' ERROR:
>   /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/app/app.component.spec.ts[2, 30]: " should be
>   ' All files pass linting. Lint warnings found in the listed files.
>   Lint errors found in the listed files. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
>   ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! myApplication-app@0.1.0 ng: `ng "lint"` npm ERR!
>   Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the myApplication-app@0.1.0
>   ng script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.

I tried the below commands to reproduce the error, but it can't be reproduced in my machine. How can I fix this error?

```
npm run ng build --prod
npm run ng build --env=prod
npm run build:prod
```

Error not showing after adding quotemak:false, I have more errors. 
1) comment must start with a space 
2) object access via string literals is disallowed 
3) Assignments in conditional expressions are forbidden etc.

How i can ignore all lint errors? 
Do i have explicitly mention for each error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is just a [TSLint](https://angular.io/cli/lint) warning, and as you might have known, TSLint is by default installed in Angular. You should just replace all double quotes(`"`) with single quotes(`'`), or you turn off the `quotemark` rule on your `tslint.json`

```
"rules": {
  "quotemark": [ false ]
}
```

Comment: error not showing after adding quotemak:false, I have more another errors. 1) comment must start with a space 2) object access via string literals is disallowed 3)  Assignments in conditional expressions are forbidden etc. How i can ingore all lint errors? Do i have explicitly mention for each error?

Comment: @ShakeerHussain yes, you will have to fix/edit your tslint rules, or fix your code based on the tslint rules.

Comment: Does anybody know the reason behind this preference of `'` over `"`?

Answer (score 1):

Edit `package.json` and add a new script entry

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint-fix": "ng lint --fix",
    ...
  },
```

And then run `lint-fix` script to fix all auto-fixable warnings raised.

```sh
npm lint-fix
```

Comment: I added  "scripts": [{ "lint": "ng lint", "lint-fix": "ng lint --fix" }]. Error 
    Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".scripts[0]" should NOT have additional properties(lint).